# ListView ActionListener

Tags: android, listview, actionlistener

I am working on a sport app,where one finds info about daily updates on matches.
i need to have a list view,with dates as header and a little preview of that dates events. on clicking this particular date on the list,full detail of the day's events are displayed.
currently,when i click a date in the list,details are shown...but for all days i have in the database : But i need to have a single day displayed with details.
Here's the code.

```
  private class displaymatches extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(JSON_URL);
        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray listavai = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");
                // looping through All matches
                for (int i = 0; i < listavai.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = listavai.getJSONObject(i);
                    dateofmatch = c.getString("dateofmatch");
                    String league = c.getString("gameleague");
                    String teams = c.getString("matches");
                    String gametime = c.getString("gametime");
                   String tip = c.getString("gametip");
                    String odds=c.getString("odds");
                    HashMap<String, String> games = new HashMap<>();
                    HashMap<String, String> gamesdetail = new HashMap<>();
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    games.put("dateofmatch", dateofmatch);
                    games.put("gameleague", league);
                    games.put("matches", teams);
                    //detailing
                    gamesdetail.put("gameleague",league);
                    gamesdetail.put("matches",teams);
                    gamesdetail.put("gametime",gametime);
                    gamesdetail.put("gametip",tip);
                    gamesdetail.put("odds",odds);
                    // adding contact to contact list
                    matcheslist.add(games);
                    detailmatchlist.add(gamesdetail);
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, matcheslist,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"dateofmatch", "gameleague",
                "matches"}, new int[]{R.id.name,
                R.id.email, R.id.mobile});

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {
              //  dateofmatch = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
               // dateofmatch
                final ListAdapter detail = new SimpleAdapter(
                        MainActivity.this, detailmatchlist,
                        R.layout.detail_list_item, new String[]{"gameleague", "matches",
                        "gametime", "gametip", "odds"}, new int[]{R.id.league,
                        R.id.matches, R.id.gametime, R.id.gametip, R.id.odds});
                    lv.setAdapter(detail);

            }
        });
    }
}







 <?php
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','root');
define('PASS','root');
define('DB','Bets');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

$sql = "select * from oddsdata";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
array_push($result,
array('dateofmatch'=>$row[0],
'gameleague'=>$row[1],
'matches'=>$row[3],
'gametime'=>$row[4],
'gametip'=>$row[5],
'odds'=>$row[6]

));
}

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: your question is unclear for me please show your json.  Match a date and get that particular JSON object using for loop.

Comment: i've added the code that fetches the data from DB. @ArpitPatel,see if you can help